# Can a fielder deliberately kick the ball over the boundary rope to keep a batsman on strike?

Tags: rules, cricket

In this potential situation the batting team has a recognized batsman and a tail ender at the crease, the recognized batsman is facing the last ball of the over and the fielding team therefore would prefer that either: he doesn't score any runs, scores 2 runs or scores a boundary so that at the start of the next over the tail ender will be on strike and not the batsman.

Supposing he hits the ball into the outfield but only takes a single run so that he retains the strike, would it be possible for the fielding team to deliberately kick the ball over the rope so that 4 runs are scored and the tail ender will then be on strike?

Clearly the situation would be pretty unsporting!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Law 19.7](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-19-boundaries/) in the MCC Laws of Cricket states that,

> If the boundary results from an overthrow or from the wilful act of a fielder the runs scored shall be
>
> (i) any runs for penalties awarded to either side AND
>
> (ii) the allowance for the boundary AND
>
> (iii) the runs completed by the batsmen, together with the run in progress if they had already crossed at the instant of the throw or act.
> Law 18.12(b) (Batsman returning to wicket he has left) shall apply as from the instant of the throw or act.

In our case, this would mean that the single that the batsman took is awarded as well as the boundary, thereby adding 5 runs to the batting team. As the single is considered, the recognized batsman will face the first delivery of the new over.

[Another source](http://www.umpires.tv/armchair/kicking_ball_over_boundary_ARC.html).

Answer (score -4):

There was an incident of an England fielder (possibly Mark Butcher ??) dropping a simple catch, and in frustration kicking the ball, which rolled out for a boundary. I think the rule is that in the case of a fielder touching the ball (but not just a parry or dropped catch over the boundary) before it goes out for a boundary then the batting side score the runs plus the boundary, and the batting positions for the following ball are as if the runs are adhered to.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the accepted answer.